# How to use prawn pdf inside a node / express app

Tags: node.js, pdf, prawn, child-process

In a node.js app I want to generate pdf docs and send it back to the user. I would like to use Prawn PDF as I have used it before and am comfortable using it.

I suppose I should use node's child_process.spawn to call a ruby script (that returns a pdf) to achieve this but I do not know how to actually implement it!

Am doing this:
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    pdf = spawn('my_ruby_script');

Now how do I get hold of the returned pdf doc?

Thanks,
mano

Comment: Aren't docs enough? — http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html. On a sidenote, I believe [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to be less akward.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response elmigranto. Am not sure how to get the rendered pdf returned by the ruby script. I will give exec a try.

Comment: Ok, I have got it now! Instead of returning the pdf from the ruby script, I should puts it so that it gets written to stdout and have the spawned process listening on stdout.

Comment: I thought you are saving pdf to file and serve it as static later, that's why I mentioned `exec`.

Comment: No, its generated on the fly and served. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this eventually:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('ruby', ['print_pdf.rb', doc_id]);
var pdf = '';
child.on('data', function(data){
    pdf += data;
});
child.on('exit', function(code){
    if(code == 0){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.send(pdf);
    }
});
```

The ruby prawn script generates the pdf and at the end just 'puts' the rendered pdf which is available to child as 'data'.